# Downloading a text file?

Tags: java, netbeans, file-io

Can anyone be able to give me assistance as im trying to get java to download a text file and output line by line and I don't know where to start.

Thanks

Comment: Google for query "java read file from url" gave me https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html which seems to perfectly answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's not that hard, here are some pointers...

- Start by creating an `URL` object
- Open a connection from this Object, which results in an `URLConnection` Object
- Get the `InputStream` from this URLConnection
- Create a new `Scanner` to read the result, one line at a time

You can find tutorials, etc. how to do all of that easily. Have fun ;-)